# $e \in C,$ then $e$ is a loop of $M,$ or $C - e$ is a circuit of $M/e.$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, matroids

Here is the relation I am trying to understand

Let $C$ be a circuit of a matroid $M.$ For e in $E(M)$:

If $e \in C,$ then $e$ is a loop of $M,$ or $C - e$ is a circuit of $M/e$ ( M contract e).

Does anyone has a justification for this idea? it is used a lot but I do not know why this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, either $C = \{e\}$ or not, if it is, then $C$ is a loop. If not, then $|C|>1$ and in $M/e$ the independents are independents of $M$ such that when added $e$ they remain independent. In this way, $C$ is not independent, so its dependent. Furthermore, because $C$ is circuit if $f\in C\setminus \{e\}$ then $C\setminus \{f\}$ is independent and so $C\setminus \{f,e\}$ is independent in $M/e$ for every $f$, hence $C\setminus \{e\}$ is minimal dependent, which is the definition of being a circuit.

Comment: I did not get the general idea of the proof, could you please elaborate the ideas you are using more?

Comment: the following statement "in $M/e$ the independents are independents of $M$ such that when added $e$ they remain independent " I do not know from where did you get this idea? Is it from proposition 3.1.7 on pg. 101?

Comment: I mean in Oxley, second edition.