# If $e \notin C,$ then $C$ is the union of circuits of $M/e$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, matroids

I want to understand why the following statement is true:

Let $C$ be a circuit of a matroid $M.$ For e in $E(M)$:

If $e \notin C,$ then $C$ is the union of circuits of $M/e.$ I understood why the following statement is true:

[$e \in C,$ then $e$ is a loop of $M,$ or $C - e$ is a circuit of $M/e.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4783696/e-in-c-then-e-is-a-loop-of-m-or-c-e-is-a-circuit-of-m-e)

I know that circuits of $M/e$ (by proposition 3.1.10) consist of minimal nonempty members of $\{ C - T: C \in \mathcal C(M)\}.$ Which I understand as the circuits in M such that when I remove from them e they remain minimal dependent in M/e. (**I hope my understanding is correct, please correct me if I am wrong**).

Still I do not know how I will get to the idea of unions of circiuts. Can someone help me please?

Comment: It would be great if you could explain what $M$, $C$, etc. are.

Comment: @kabenyuk I edited my question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalently, we need to prove that every $f \in C$ is contained in some circuit that is a subset of $C$ in $M/e$. Assume the contrary, this implies that for every independent set $J$ contained within $C$ in $M/e$ such that $f \not \in J$, we have $J \cup f$ also being independent. Alternatively, for every independent set $J$ contained within $C \cup e$ in $M$ such that $e \in J$ and $f \not \in J$, we have $J \cup f$ also being independent.

Why is this a problem? Well, first note that if $(C - f) \cup e$ is independent, then we would have $C \cup e$ also being independent, which is impossible since $C$ is a circuit. Thus, $C-f$ is independent but $(C-f) \cup e$ is dependent. Let $D$ be the fundamental circuit of $(C-f)$ with respect to $e$. Note that $D \neq \{e\}$ (if $e$ were a loop, contraction would not be well-defined). Let $g \in D$ be such that $g \neq e$. Now, $C$ and $D$ are two circuits with $g \in C \cap D$. It follows that there exists some circuit contained in $C \cup D - g$.

Since $C \cup D - g$ is dependent and contains both $e$ and $f$, we know by our assumption that $C \cup D - g - f$ is also dependent. However, this is contained in $(C - f) \cup e$ and must thus contain $D$, and this is certainly not the case since it does not contain $g$. Thus, we have the required contradiction.

Comment: Could you clarify please why this is an equivalent statement to what is required to be proved "Equivalently, we need to prove that every $f \in C$ is contained in some circuit that is a subset of $C$ in $M/e$."?

Comment: why if $(C - f) \cup e$ is independent, then we would have $C \cup e$ also being independent? could you clarify more please?

Comment: @Brain The statement is equivalent since if $C$ is a union of circuits in $M/e$, then every $f \in C$ is contained in one of these circuits, and in the other direction, if every $f \in C$ is contained in some circuit that is a subset of $C$ in $M/e$, then $C$ is the union of these circuits over all $f \in C$.

Comment: @Brain The end of the first paragraph comes to the following conclusion: if we assume the contrary, then for any independent set $J$ contained in $C \cup e$ inside $M$, with $e \in J$ and $f \not \in J$, then $J \cup f$ is also independent. We have applied this to $J = (C - f) \cup e$.

Comment: Can we use the strong elimination axiom of circuits? Or did you use it? Maybe I did not understand that you did.

Comment: I didn't use the strong elimination axiom, just the regular elimination axiom. If any of the steps confuses you, perhaps you could tell me which part is unclear, and I could try to clarify.

Comment: can you please recap the steps of your proof in one or two sentences?

Comment: Well, there are a lot of important details in the proof, but if I had to summarize, the first paragraph writes a condition equivalent to the negation of what we want to prove, and the rest of the proof shows why this condition cannot hold.

Comment: I still did not get the rest of paragraph 1. Why the contrary implies what you said?

Comment: Because if $J \subseteq C$ is independent and does not contain $f$, then $J \cup f$ being dependent would imply that $f$ is contained in the fundamental circuit of $J$, which is a circuit contained in $C$.

Comment: why you are differentiating 2 cases, when J \subseteq C and when $J \subseteq C \cup e$?